# EL Messages on JSP page

Tags: jsp-tags

i have some server side validations and am displaying validation messages in JSP using EL like
 ${requestScope.validatemessage} where validatemessage is the message i set in Java file
its working fine
But the problem the message is still displaying even if i refresh the page
how to disappear this message on refresh?
plz let me know asap

thanks in advance,
anu

Answer (score 0):

Is your browser caching the page? Try Ctrl-F5.

Are you running this on Tomcat? Try shutting down Tomcat and deleting its /work drectory. 
That will get rid of Tomcat's cached copy.